# Convert String array to an Int array and total it

Tags: java, arrays, io, inputstream, outputstream

I need to create a program that accepts input from a file. I need to ask the user to enter two(2) variables, the interest rate and months for the loan. I then calculate the monthly payment, output the original input from the file along with the number of months on the loan and the monthly payment.

I am having issues with getting the numbers in the array to int's so that I can calculate them. I have tried a few things, but cannot get this to do what I want. After reading through some other questions I was able to find how to convert the array to an int and get the sum so I have included this in the code. I know how to do the calculations after I get the array of "item" to an int. I am only looking for assistance on the part of converting item[1] to an array that I can use to calculate the sum of the items. I have included comments in the code that might better show what I'm looking for.

This is what the input file looks like:

```
Driver  425

Putter  200
 
Wedges  450
 
Hybrid  175
```

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment3t {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
   File inputFile = new File("Project3.txt");
   File outputFile = new File("Project3Output.txt");
   
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
   BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
   
   System.out.print("Enter the interest rate: ");
   float interestRate = scanner.nextFloat();
   
   System.out.print("Enter months for the loan: ");
   int  loanMonths = scanner.nextInt();
   
   try {
      bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile)); 
      bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
      String line;
      
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null) {
         String[] item = line.split("\\s+");//create an array. This is the part I cant figure out. It creates the array, but I cant figure out how to get this data to "results" below.
         
         int[] results = Stream.of(item).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(); //converts the string array to an int array.
         int sum = Arrays.stream(results).sum();  //calculates the sum of the array after its converted to an int to use in the monthly payment calculation.
         
         bufferedWriter.write(line);
         bufferedWriter.newLine();
      }
      
      bufferedWriter.write("Number of months of the loan:         " + String.valueOf(loanMonths));

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();   
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
      try {
         bufferedReader.close();
         bufferedWriter.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: How does the input data relate to loan calculations?  Please correct the information in your question to match the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *input* consists of alternating *numeric* and *non-numeric* data. And after splitting the line on white spaces with `split("\\s+")` you are trying all the strings into `int`. That will inevitably lead to `NumberFormatException` at runtime.

To avoid that you need to add a `filter()` to the stream to ensure that only strings that are comprised of digits will be parsed.

And since you are using `int[] results` only as a source of the second stream that calculates the `sum` then you should get rid of redundancy. There's no need to create a second stream and allocate in memory unused array.

Another mistake is that the scope of the variable `sum` is limited to the `while` loop. And according to your example of the input, a line will contain only at most *only one digit*. That doesn't make much sense and I think that wasn't your intention.

Here is one of the ways how to resolve these issues:

```
    int sum = 0;
    try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(inputFile.toPath())) {
        sum = getSum(lines);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Note** that [**try-with-resources**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is a preferred way to deal with resources that implement `AutoCloseable`. When execution of the `try` block finishes (normally or abruptly) all resources will be closed.

Logic for calculating the **sum**:

```
public static int getSum(Stream<String> lines) {
    return lines.flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")))
            .filter(str -> str.matches("\\d+"))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .sum();
}
```

That basically the answer to the question:

> Convert String array to an Int array and total it

To fix other parts of your code you have to have a clear understanding of what you are trying to achieve. There is a lot of actions packed together in this code, you need to split it into separate methods each with its own responsibility.

The code for writing to the `outputFile` seems to be unrelated to the process of calculating the sum. Basically, you are creating a copy of the `inputFile` with only one additional line: `"Number of months of the loan: " + String.valueOf(loanMonths)`.

If you insist these actions must be done at the same time, for instance, the `inputFile` could be large, then it might be done like this:

```
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
            if (!line.isBlank()) {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\s+")[1]);
            }
        }
        writer.write("Number of months of the loan: " + String.valueOf(loanMonths));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Note** that in this case, Java 8 streams are not needed because a line can contain only a single value and there's nothing to process with a stream.